# How to make server pages interact with cordova

Tags: cordova, oracle-apex, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing a mobile application using cordova 6.0 .
At the first page of it (/www/index.html) there is a redirection to the first page of my web application.

On the server I'm using oracle application express so that I can develop my mobile application very easy, but the point is I don't have cordova on the server and I can't use mobile native features like camera.

What are the necessary files that I need to upload to my server, or other things to do to make my web application server interact with cordova and get access to mobile native features ?

here is actually what I want to do in the first page of application :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>My app</title>
    <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
    // Empty
    }
    function listener(event) {
    if (event.origin !== "http://apex.oracle.com") return;
    if (event.data == "vibrate") {
    navigator.notification.vibrate(2000);
    }
    }
    if (window.addEventListener) {
    addEventListener("message", listener, false);
    } else {
    attachEvent("onmessage", listener);
    }
    </script>
    <style type='text/css'>
    body,html,iframe {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <iframe src='http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=41097:2' id='iframe'></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please be informed that Apache Cordova is an open-source mobile development framework. It allows you to use standard web technologies - HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript for cross-platform development. Cordova has nothing to do with server side components. Please rephrase the question so that we can understand what you actually expect

Comment: @Gandhi thanks for your comment, I add the code to the post too, hope you'll get what I mean to do

Comment: Sorry looking at your code i still understand why you want device native features on server side. You gotta clearly state what is the issue you facing to help out better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are trying to load pages from server and make them interact with native feature like `phonegap` does, but problem arise when you are trying to integrate `phonegap` framework to server pages. Simply you can not do that because even if you will include `cordova.js` it will not be able to interact with native files that are vital for native feature.

Comment: It's done in "Oracle Application Express for Mobile Application", I add the code to the main post, hope you will get what i mean

Comment: It mean to use native feature you will have to make interation of `phonegap` html page with the page you are loading in `iframe`. How you plan on doing that ?

Comment: like you said the cordova.js file is on the server too, and it is used in application pages, but actually it deosn't work for me, I think it is because of the difference of cordova version that is used in the book, some structure has been changed and I can't figure out what is the problem

Comment: Yes `cordova.js` file requires `cordova_plugin.js` where mapping to plugins and native file package are done. But perhaps that will not be able to do mapping. One more thing you dont have plugins folder on your server where javascripts file of plugins are.

Comment: @hva.narola Could you please explain what you really tried to answer? How can you include cordova.js file to server pages? What you mean by interacting with native files?

Comment: Simple. Server page that is being sourced in `iframe` can not interact with plugins of phonegap or native files. @Gandhi

Comment: Just another thing, if we include all the js files and plugin files in the server in the way that it should be, again it won't help ?

Comment: no it won't be able to create bridge to native files like that creates when files are in application itself.